# C++ read any windows user HKEY using username/SID or Alternate

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, registry, credential-providers

I have created an application, which works for all the windows users (Local, AD, Azure etc). For every user, I'm storing some data inside HKEY_CurrentUer\TESTApp\ registry. Now in the custom credential provider (LOGINUI) once the user enters the credential Wants to read that user HKEY_{...}\TESTApp\ details to know more about the user.

I can successfully store user details in HKEY_CurrentUer\TESTApp\ registry and read details from HKEY_USERS\SID\TESTApp\ if he already login's in.

Now I have the following question,

1. Is it possible to do the same for not logged in or log out users using either username/SID?
2. Is there any other HKEY place where I can store the user details and can easily read using username/SID without admin permission? For now, I want to maintain the user details in the machine itself (no cloud).
3. At last, if the above two is not possible, can I create and read a file with key-pair values in my app workspace without any permission issue?

Since I'm new to windows app development, correct me if I'm doing wrong.  THANKS in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. `HKEY_USERS\SID` will be created only after successfully logon on this machine and continue to reside after logout.
2. If you are talking about logon scenario for credential provider `CPUS_LOGON` means that your credential provider is working with highest privileges for application - as a `SYSTEM` user, and you can read and write practically everywhere.